# Vimscript: how do I get the OS that is running Vim?

Tags: vim

I've got vim plugin that runs on different machines and sometimes needs to do things differently depending on whether it's Windows, Linux, Mac.

What's easiest way to test for the operating system?  I know I could parse the output of :version command. Is there something simpler that will reveal the OS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From google: 
You can use `has()` and the list of features under `:help feature-list` to
determine what type of Vim (and therefore under which OS is running).

```
if has('win32')
   ... win32 specific stuff ...
endif
```

Search for "version of Vim" from the feature-list help topic and that
should bring you to the different versions for which you can check.

Comment: I use this in my vimrc to specify different fonts for Windows vs Linux.

Comment: John -- Thanks a lot.  That's something I thought I'd seen before but wasn't able to find when I started looking through docs specifically.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @John's answer here is a full list of possible operating systems:

```
"▶2 os.fullname
for s:os.fullname in ["unix", "win16", "win32", "win64", "win32unix", "win95",
            \         "mac", "macunix", "amiga", "os2", "qnx", "beos", "vms"]
    if has(s:os.fullname)
        break
    endif
    let s:os.fullname='unknown'
endfor
"▶2 os.name
if s:os.fullname[-3:] is 'nix' || s:os.fullname[:2] is 'mac' ||
            \s:os.fullname is 'qnx' || s:os.fullname is 'vms'
    let s:os.name='posix'
elseif s:os.fullname[:2] is 'win'
    let s:os.name='nt'
elseif s:os.fullname is 'os2'
    let s:os.name='os2'
else
    let s:os.name='other'
endif
"▲2
```

This is the code used by my frawor plugin for determining current operating system.

Comment: In addition to those array values, there are a few `gui_...` features.  `gui_gnome` and `gui_gtk` could be used to isolate some flavors of linux.

Comment: This won't work correctly for Mac OS X. It will claim the OS is `unix`. Note that moving `mac`/`macunix` up won't make a difference; while MacVim has both of those features, the system-provided Vim returns `0` for both `mac` and `macunix`. So those features really just test for MacVim, not for Vim running on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my love of Python:

```
python << endpython
import sys
sys.platform
endpython
```

Also maybe `os.name` if needed.